# What is the best way to handle waiting for elements that are not always present with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

For example if I have a code like this:

```
<div id='parent'>
  <div class='profile-pic'>...</div>
  <p class='email'>I'm not always present</p>
  <span class='name'>John Smith</span>
</div>
```

Now this is a random example. But should help to visualize what I mean. I want to grab profile picture, email and the name. None of them are necessarily always present on the page.

I could set a wait for each element separately like this:

```
try:
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'email')))
except:
  pass
```

But that would mean every time one or more elements are not present on the page I would wait 10 seconds for each of them. Now let's say I have 20 elements like this that can be present but are not always and I have 1000 pages to go through. This approach would take forever.

Now that's where my question comes in. What is the best solution to handle cases like this? Or is this something that should not be done with Selenium at all?

What I have been doing so far is selecting the parent element and waiting for it to load but as I have learned that does not guarantee that all the children are loaded.

Comment: Wait for the parent element to be present and just do check if the "not always present" element is present (not waiting) - example with is_displayed() which returns true/false. You can build the logic based on condition check.

Comment: Wouldn't that return false when the parent is loaded but the children have not loaded yet? @Infern0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is to iterate over parent elements.
For each parent element wait for it's presence.
I can't know if parent element here is visible or not.
In case parent element is visible - wait for it visibility.
Now, wait for desired child element visibility.
Here you can use a short timeout since this timeout is for use in case the parent element is already present (but maybe still not fully loaded) while child element is still need to be loaded.
2-3 seconds should be more that enough here until you have very bad internet connectivity / loading is done extremmely low.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah this is something I also thought of doing myself but wondered if there is a better/more efficient way of doing it. Because if there are lots of elements I need to grab from the page even those short loading times will add up if there are lots of pages to go through.

Comment: Finding the parent element will take exactly the time it takes to load that element. In case the child element is present no time will be spent more than the actual time it took to load that element, normally this will take 0 time. The only extra time you will spend is on non-existing child elements. But since it will be 2-3 seconds it will add non significant delay comparing to the total time you will need to go thru all those pages.

Comment: Probably there are better approaches, but this will not be Selenium. Maybe something like beautifulsoup - the tool I'm less familiar with. Anyway, going thru multiple websites will anyway take significant time. Especially if doing that with UI tools

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now, sorry I understood you wrong at first. Yes, this makes much more sense now. Thanks a lot, I think this could work. @Prophet

Comment: I'm always happy to assist

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct than you only want to proceed further if all 3 required elements are present then you can try below approaches

#1 Below code repeatedly tries to find the desired elements until all of them are found.The NoSuchElementException is caught when the element is not found, and the loop waits for a short time before trying again, but in this approach you have to specify every locator

```
while True:
    try:
        email = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME('email'))
        profile_pic = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME('profile-pic'))
        name = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME('name'))
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        time.sleep(1)
```

#2 If you have a common locator to identify the elements, below approach can be useful when you don't know the exact number of elements that will be present on the page, but you know there must be at least a certain number for your script to work correctly.We use `findelements` method inside the loop to check for the number of elements with the the given locator, and the loop sleeps for 1 second between each check. Once the desired number of elements are found, the loop exits and the script can continue to use the elements as needed.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '')))
while len(elements) < 10:
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('')
    time.sleep(1)

# Now we have at least 10 email elements
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer but no I don't want necessarily continue only when all of the fields are present but I do want to make sure that if they would appear on the page then they would be included and if not then just continue with the ones that are present.